# Reference to input field added dynamically to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of the jsp pages of my project, I have this jquery code, which fill a table with dynamic data from server (the json strings):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var obj_data = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"Data":[{"data":"2014-04-10","string":"10/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-11","string":"11/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-12","string":"12/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-13","string":"13/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-14","string":"14/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-15","string":"15/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-16","string":"16/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-17","string":"17/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-18","string":"18/MAR"},{"data":"2014-04-19","string":"19/MAR"}]}' );
    var obj_hora = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"Hora":[{"hora":"04:30:00","string":"4:30-4:30"},{"hora":"05:00:00","string":"5:0-5:0"},{"hora":"05:30:00","string":"5:30-5:30"},{"hora":"06:00:00","string":"6:0-6:0"},{"hora":"06:30:00","string":"6:30-6:30"},{"hora":"07:00:00","string":"7:0-7:0"},{"hora":"07:30:00","string":"7:30-7:30"},{"hora":"08:00:00","string":"8:0-8:0"},{"hora":"08:30:00","string":"8:30-8:30"},{"hora":"09:00:00","string":"9:0-9:0"},{"hora":"09:30:00","string":"9:30-9:30"},{"hora":"10:00:00","string":"10:0-10:0"}]}' );
    var obj_horario = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"Horario":[{"horario":"2014-04-11 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-11","string_data":"11/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-11 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-11","string_data":"11/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-11 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-11","string_data":"11/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-12 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-12","string_data":"12/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-12 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-12","string_data":"12/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-12 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-12","string_data":"12/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-13 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-13","string_data":"13/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-13 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-13","string_data":"13/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-13 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-13","string_data":"13/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-14 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-14","string_data":"14/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-14 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-14","string_data":"14/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-14 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-14","string_data":"14/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-15 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-15","string_data":"15/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-15 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-15","string_data":"15/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-15 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-15","string_data":"15/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-16 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-16","string_data":"16/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-16 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-16","string_data":"16/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-16 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-16","string_data":"16/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-17 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-17","string_data":"17/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-17 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-17","string_data":"17/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-17 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-17","string_data":"17/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-18 06:00:00","data":"2014-04-18","string_data":"18/MAR","hora":"06:00:00","string_hora":"6:0-6:0"},{"horario":"2014-04-18 06:30:00","data":"2014-04-18","string_data":"18/MAR","hora":"06:30:00","string_hora":"6:30-6:30"},{"horario":"2014-04-18 07:00:00","data":"2014-04-18","string_data":"18/MAR","hora":"07:00:00","string_hora":"7:0-7:0"}]}' );

    var newRow1 = $('<tr>');
    for(var item in obj_hora.Hora) {
        newCol1 = "<td></td>";
        for(var item2 in obj_data.Data) {
            newCol1 += '<td>' + obj_data.Data[item2].string + '</td>';
        }
    }
    newRow1.append(newCol1);
    $("table.horarios").append(newRow1);

    var counter = 1;
    var newRow2 = "";
    for(var item in obj_hora.Hora) {
        newRow2 = $('<tr>');
        newCol2 = '<td>' + obj_hora.Hora[item].string + '</td>';
        for(var item2 in obj_data.Data) {
            newCol2 += '<td>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="horario" data-key_data="'+obj_data.Data[item2].data+'" data-key_hora="'+obj_hora.Hora[item].hora+'" name="'+counter+'">' + '</td>';
            for(var index in obj_horario.Horario) {
                if(obj_hora.Hora[item].hora == obj_horario.Horario[index].hora && obj_data.Data[item2].data == obj_horario.Horario[index].data)
                    $('input[name='+counter+']').attr("checked", "true");
            }
            counter++;
        }
        newRow2.append(newCol2);
        $("table.horarios").append(newRow2);
    }

});
```

My problem is with this line:

```
for(var index in obj_horario.Horario) {
                if(obj_hora.Hora[item].hora == obj_horario.Horario[index].hora && obj_data.Data[item2].data == obj_horario.Horario[index].data)
                    $('input[name='+counter+']').attr("checked", "true");
            }
```

that line should make the checkbox with similar values of date and time checked, but when I run the application and open this page, nothing is checked, despite I have data in the variable 'obj_horario', as you can see in the code above.

Someone can see what i am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I change the code highlight above to this:

```
        for(var index in obj_horario.Horario) {
            if(obj_hora.Hora[item].hora == obj_horario.Horario[index].hora && obj_data.Data[item2].data == obj_horario.Horario[index].data) {
                console.info('counter='+counter);
                console.info('Hora = ' + obj_hora.Hora[item].hora + '| Horario.hora = ' + obj_horario.Horario[index].hora);
                console.info('Data = ' + obj_data.Data[item2].data + '| Horario.data = ' + obj_horario.Horario[index].data);
                var checkbox = $('input[name='+counter+']');
                $(checkbox).attr("checked", "true");
            }
        }
```

to include the console.info() function; now, i can see in the browser console that the itens  which should be checked are being selected correctly by the if sentence, but i guess this snippet of the code:

```
                var checkbox = $('input[name='+counter+']');
                $(checkbox).attr("checked", "true");
```

aren't working properly. My guess it's because it is referring a dynamically created object - I have a similar problem before, and solve including the dynamic object inside a static one, and binding an event to this static element, but now I can't figure out how to do the same, since I'm triggering any event, just are adding the element to the page.

Anyone can point me a direction for solving this?

Comment: Hi. If you got the same json data, I don't think the problem is in the for in part. This is the o/p I got when I am trying.

for(var i in obj_hora.Hora)
{
   if(obj_hora.Hora[i].hora == obj_horario.Horario[i].hora)
   {
      console.info('Hora = ' + obj_hora.Hora[i].hora)
      console.info('Horario = ' + obj_horario.Horario[i].hora)
   }
}

Hora = 06:00:00, Horario = 06:00:00

Hora = 06:30:00, Horario = 06:30:00

Hora = 07:00:00, Horario = 07:00:00

Could you post the html part also ? And have you got any error in the console tool ?

Comment: the full code of the page is this: https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/horario/cadastra.jsp

Comment: and no, I do not have any error in the console tool (I am using the google chrome now, but i tested in mozilla firefox too, both in kubuntu linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part:

```
for(var item in obj_hora.Hora) {
    newRow2 = $('<tr>');
    newCol2 = '<td>' + obj_hora.Hora[item].string + '</td>';
    for(var item2 in obj_data.Data) {
        newCol2 += '<td>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="horario" data-key_data="'+obj_data.Data[item2].data+'" data-key_hora="'+obj_hora.Hora[item].hora+'" name="'+counter+'">' + '</td>';
        for(var index in obj_horario.Horario) {
            if(obj_hora.Hora[item].hora == obj_horario.Horario[index].hora && obj_data.Data[item2].data == obj_horario.Horario[index].data)
                $('input[name='+counter+']').attr("checked", "true");
        }
        counter++;
    }
    newRow2.append(newCol2);
    $("table.horarios").append(newRow2);
}
```

you are not appending newCol2 to the DOM (with .append()) until the end of the for loop. As a result, within the for loop, where your $('input [name='+counter+']') gets executed, there is not (yet) such an element within the DOM.

Possible solutions:

(1st solution) Add this for loop after your .append() (so after the code snippet you pasted):

```
for(var item in obj_hora.Hora) {
    for(var item2 in obj_data.Data) {
        for(var index in obj_horario.Horario) {
            if(obj_hora.Hora[item].hora == obj_horario.Horario[index].hora && obj_data.Data[item2].data == obj_horario.Horario[index].data)
                $('input[name='+counter+']').attr("checked", "true");
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

(2nd solution) Replace your original code with something like this:

```
for(var item in obj_hora.Hora) {
    newRow2 = $('<tr>');
    newCol2 = '<td>' + obj_hora.Hora[item].string + '</td>';
    newRow2.append(newCol2);
    for(var item2 in obj_data.Data) {

        newCol2 = '<td>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="horario" data-key_data="'+obj_data.Data[item2].data+'" data-key_hora="'+obj_hora.Hora[item].hora+'" name="'+counter+'">' + '</td>';
        newRow2.append(newCol2);
        for(var index in obj_horario.Horario) {
            if(obj_hora.Hora[item].hora == obj_horario.Horario[index].hora && obj_data.Data[item2].data == obj_horario.Horario[index].data)
                $('input[name='+counter+']').attr("checked", "true");
        }
        counter++;
    }

    $("table.horarios").append(newRow2);
}
```